# Visual Studio: Unable to start debugging.Operation Not Supported

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I am facing strange error in visual studio, whenever I try to debug the asp.net application it shows me the following prompt and doesn't allow me to run the application, I already installed visual studio few times, and cleared all cache and registry entry before each installation, but still didn't work, your help is appreciated.

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I am writing the answer here, 
we need to select the browser, from the list

please see image [image]